# confused with conditionals

Tags: sentence-meaning, conditional-constructions

I've got confused with first and second conditional in the following sentence:

> You'd never get there unless you go by jet.

and

> You'd never get there unless you went by jet.

I'd like to know whether both are correct in structure and what's the difference in the meaning.

Comment: I am not sure about your main question about the tense for *go*, but as a side point, when you use *go by* to talk about a generic method of transportation, you don't use an article.  It should simply be *go by jet* or *went by jet*.  If you want to emphasize a specific vehicle, you could say *go in a jet*.

Comment: Actually, as you said, the tenses were the problem. Articles were my mistakes. I changed them. tnx!

Answer (score 2):

As a native US English speaker, the second sentence sounds more correct. The first one seems like it's mixing tenses.

If I know someone is planning to go for certain, I might say:

> You'll never get there unless you go by jet.

If someone is just thinking or dreaming about going, but it's more hypothetical, not a concrete plan, I might say:

> You'd never get there unless you went by jet.